# Функция exec возвращает None вместо результата введенного выражения

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

У меня пробный код с использованием функции `exec`.

```
s = input()
print(exec(s))
```

Я ввёл в командную строку:

```
l = 'abc'
```

В итоге в командной строке выводит `None`.

Как это работает и как сделать так, чтобы в командной строке вывело `'abc'`?

Comment: А почему вы ожидаете 'abc'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В документации к [функции exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) сказано:

> The return value is None.

Выводится значение возврата функции, ожидать получить что-то другое не стоит.

```py
>>> s = input ()
l = 'abc'
>>> print (exec (s))
None
>>> l
'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы присваиваете переменной 's' уже значение.. что бы был результат, вы должны ввести в input чему s должна быть равна, в нашем случае нужно вывести abc, тогда делаем так:

Запускаем код > пишем: print('abc') > получаем результат от процесса exec.

```
s = input()

exec(s)
```